# Drawing non-polyline smoothed lines with `gpu` module

Tags: python, shaders, gpu, antialiasing, bgl

Backstory:

Since `bgl` module will soon to be deprecated and it's doesn't work on Metal already I was trying to move code to `gpu` module. The tricky part is implementing smoothed lines. The first way I've found how to do it is to either use `3D_POLYLINE_UNIFORM_COLOR` [builtin shader](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/main/source/blender/gpu/shaders/gpu_shader_3D_polyline_geom.glsl) or to reimplement polylines in your shader yourself. It's cumbersome when you have many shaders because this algorithm requires both replacing all occurences of `EmitVertex` in your shader and you also need to always provide the edge direction to it, it also creates some additional vertices. And I've found [some more simple algorithm](https://vitaliburkov.wordpress.com/2016/09/17/simple-and-fast-high-quality-antialiased-lines-with-opengl/) that I was trying to implement but met some issues.

Question:

I've wrote the shader trying to make smoothed lines without implementing `POLYLINE_UNIFORM_COLOR` algorithm but it doesn't really work. Any ideas what can be wrong?
Main issues:

- smoothing doesn't seem to work
- on increasing blend factor some non edge part of the lines start disappearing
- on zooming out line thickness stays the same

[image]

Shader code (just run this script in default blender scene, parameters to play with - `line_width` and `blend_factor` in scene custom properties):

```py
import bpy
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader


polyline_vert_glsl = """
uniform vec2 viewportSize;
out vec2 vLineCenter;
uniform mat4 ModelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform vec4 color;

in vec3 pos;

void main(void)
{
  vec4 pp = ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);;
  gl_Position = pp;
  vLineCenter = 0.5*(pp.xy + vec2(1, 1)) * viewportSize;
};
"""

polyline_frag_glsl = """
uniform float lineWidth;
uniform float blendFactor; //1.5..2.5
uniform vec2 viewportSize;

in vec2 vLineCenter;
out vec4 fragColor;

void main(void)
{
  float d;
  float alpha;
  alpha = 1.0;
  d = length((gl_FragCoord.xy-vLineCenter)/viewportSize);

  if (d > lineWidth) {
    alpha = 0.0;
  } else {
    alpha = pow(float((lineWidth-d)/lineWidth), blendFactor);
  }

  fragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, alpha);
};
"""

from mathutils import Vector
coords = [(-1, 0, -1), (1, 0, -1), (1, 0, 1), (-1, 0, 1)]
line_color = (1,1,0,1)
bpy.context.scene['line_width'] = 3.0
bpy.context.scene['blend_factor'] = 1.5


def draw():
    shader = gpu.types.GPUShader(
        polyline_vert_glsl, 
        polyline_frag_glsl, 
    )
    batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'LINES', {"pos": coords}, indices=((0, 2), (1, 3)))

    region = bpy.context.region
    region_3d = bpy.context.region_data

    projection_matrix = gpu.matrix.get_projection_matrix()
    model_view_matrix = gpu.matrix.get_model_view_matrix()
    mvp_matrix = projection_matrix @ model_view_matrix # same as region_3d.perspective_matrix
    viewport_size = [region.width, region.height]

    shader.bind()
    shader.uniform_float("viewportSize", viewport_size)
    shader.uniform_float("ModelViewProjectionMatrix", mvp_matrix)
    shader.uniform_float("lineWidth", bpy.context.scene['line_width'])
    shader.uniform_float("blendFactor", bpy.context.scene['blend_factor'])

    # seems to be clamped at 9.5
    gpu.state.line_width_set(9.5)
    gpu.state.blend_set("ALPHA")
    batch.draw(shader)

bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')
```